# Recorrer valores creando new JProperty

Tags: c#, json

Estoy tratando de crear un Json a partir de unos datos, el problema que tengo es que teniendo:

```
class Credentials
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}



        List<Credentials> credentials = new List<Credentials> {
        new Credentials{
            Name = "login",
            Value = "loginValue"
        },

         new Credentials
         {
            Name = "password",
            Value = "secret"
         }
        };
```

Como puedo introducir todos los valores de `credentials` en mi Json?

Mi código actual:

```
     var r =   new JProperty("credentials", new JObject(
           new JProperty(credentials[0].Name, credentials[0].Value
           )));
```

Trate de recorrer toda la longitud de mi Lista de objetos usando `foreach` y linq, pero sin éxito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo estás usando la librería [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).

**Serializando**

Para serializar un objeto, es tan sencillo como usar [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm), esta función, recibe un object, y retorna un string con el Json resultante.

Por ejemplo

```
List<Credentials> credentials = new List<Credentials> {
    new Credentials{
        Name = "login",
        Value = "loginValue"
    },

    new Credentials
    {
        Name = "password",
        Value = "secret"
    }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials);
Console.WriteLine(json);
//Salida [{"Name":"login","Value":"loginValue"},{"Name":"password","Value":"secret"}]
```

En caso de que necesites, también podes definir el formato del Json resultante con el enum [`Formatting`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm)

Por ejemplo,

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials, Formatting.Indented);
```

Produciría:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "login",
    "Value": "loginValue"
  },
  {
    "Name": "password",
    "Value": "secret"
  }
]
```

**Deserializando**

Con esta librería, deserializar un json en un objeto, también es muy sencillo, usando la función genérica [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm)

Donde basta, definir el tipo genérico, como la clase con la estructura del archivo Json, y el string que contiene el json pasarlo como parámetro.

Por ejemplo:

```
List<Credentials> credenciales = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Credentials>>(jsonString);
```